# Resize Image Keep Aspect Ratio White Line Border

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

Im using the following code (adapted from [Example #2 here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2941/Resizing-a-Photographic-image-with-GDI-for-NET) ) to Resize an Image keeping the aspect ratio.But i keep getting a white border around the resized images.What im i doing wrong.

```
 Bitmap ResizekeepAspectRatio(Bitmap imgPhoto, int Width, int Height)
            {
                int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
                int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
                int sourceX = 0;
                int sourceY = 0;
                int destX = 0;
                int destY = 0;

                float nPercent = 0;
                float nPercentW = 0;
                float nPercentH = 0;

                nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
                nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);
                if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
                {
                    nPercent = nPercentH;
                    destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((Width -
                                  (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    nPercent = nPercentW;
                    destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((Height -
                                  (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
                }

                int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
                int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

                Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height,
                                  PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                                 imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

                Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
                grPhoto.Clear(Color.White);
                grPhoto.InterpolationMode =
                        InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
                    new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
                    new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                grPhoto.Dispose();
                return bmPhoto;
            }
```

**UPDATE:**

Sample Resized Image

[image]

***Zooming*** in Corner Reveals White Border

[image]

Comment: `float` is probably causing the calculations to be 1 pixel short. Change `float` to `double`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks ...Actually the answer below solved the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the line

```
Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height,
                              PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
To 
 Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight,
                          PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

Since you want to keep the aspect ratio most of the time you will end up having extra space around the image so if you don't need that extra space then make the new picture size fit to the new destination size

Edit:

```
Try to comment out the line grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
```

Comment: Thanks .. but I'm not talking about the extra space... I have used another Crop Function to Crop that off.Im talking about the white line border within the image... Have you seen the Update..

Comment: Try to comment out the line  grPhoto.InterpolationMode =                    InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

Comment: Thanks... it worked... what was the issue? Will commenting out this line reduce output image quality?

Comment: I don't think that will reduce the image quality, but you can try it and compare the images using InterpolationMode  and without using it..

Comment: Do you mind updating your answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: The white line border still exists for some images.